# Applying future posts filter to wordpress get_posts

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to show first three future post previews in wordpress page using get_posts, so I did:

```
/* function.php */
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {

    global $wp_query;

    if (is_array($wp_query->query_vars['post_status'])){

        if ( in_array('publish',$wp_query->query_vars['post_status'])){
        // posts today into the future
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')) . "'";
        }
    }
    return $where;
}

function textdomain_future_posts( $query ) {
        //$query->set('numberposts','3');
        //$query->set('category','1');
        //$query->set('post_status','publish');
        $query->set('orderby','post_date');
        $query->set('order','ASC');
        add_filter('posts_where','filter_where');
        return $query;
}

/* index.php */
global $post;
add_action('pre_get_posts','textdomain_future_posts');
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category=1');
$i=1;
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
.
.
.
.
```

But looks it doesn't really filter for date > today.... Shall I have missed something maybe?

thanks in advance!
Cheers
Luigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved by myself:

I put in functions.php this function:

```
function show_future_posts($posts)
{
   global $wp_query, $wpdb;
   if(is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0)
   {
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request);
   }
   return $posts;
}
add_filter('the_posts', 'show_future_posts');
```

so in this way I can list future posts with get_posts('...post_status=future..'); and open them without problems

Thanks to everyone

Cheers,
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

`pre_get_posts` should be used to modify the main loop and not `get_posts()`.

Try the following instead:

```
$myposts = get_posts( array(
    'cat'            => 1,
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'order_by'       => 'post_date',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_status'    => 'future',
) );
```

Here you don't need to use a custom where query. You're getting 3 posts marked as future ordered by date (ascending).

Comment: Hello Nathan, if I use "future" when I click to those posts I can't open them because they are just future... is there a way to force opening them ? Otherwise the only way is to change post_state to "publish" and put in get_posts options post_date > today and how I can add that condition ?